# Best way to count visitors?

Tags: plugins, count

I want to count how many people visit my wordpress-website an want to know the following data:

- visitors per day/week/month/year (with history)
- which subpage/article attracts the most visitors

Is there a plugin that can do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a number of ways of achieving this but the two ways I would concider would be

- **Google analytics** - http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/google-analytics-for-wordpress/
- **Wordpress Sitestats** - http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/stats/ or install http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/jetpack/ as it comes with that.

Comment: _"Future upgrades to WordPress.com Stats will only be available in Jetpack."_ So, it's better to install **[Jetpack by WordPress.com](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/jetpack/)** and disable all the modules except **WordPress.com Stats**. But IMO, the combo of **[Google Analytics](https://www.google.com/analytics/) + [Google Analytics for WordPress](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/google-analytics-for-wordpress/)** plugin is more flexible, if not simply better.